# custom UITableViewCells are ALWAYS null when they are not shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with height 180px which allows only to display 5 rows at a time, the table view contains custom cells. However, I have 6 cells, that means the sixth cell will be shown only when using the scroll, when I try to loop through all cells like this:

```
  for (int row = 0; row < [self.autoTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; row++)  {

    NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.autoTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];

    if(!cell)
        NSLog(@"NULL %i", row);

 }
```

At runtime, if I didn't do a scroll I get an `NSLog` statement in the console window which says: `NULL 5`, and when I scroll down to show the last cell I get an `NSLog` statement which says: `NULL 0`, I keep getting this `NSLog` all the time when I scroll up and down, why the hell this happens, although all cells are already created ?

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` code is:

```
static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"customCell";
EditableTableDataRow *cell = nil;

cell = (EditableTableDataRow *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[EditableTableDataRow alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:customCellIdentifier itemPadding:0 scaleToFill:NO] autorelease];
}
```

then I do various things on labels and text fields  that are inside this custom cell, and finally:

```
...

 return cell;
```

thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That's the default behavior. When cells are not being shown, they are deallocated from memory.
Every modification that you do to them should be done in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, that's when they are created. Have your data loaded into memory so by the time the cell is created, it can get filled up quickly. That's how you get a smooth scrolling.

Comment: so, is there a way to loop through all cells and do a modification on each cell inside the loop (for shown + hidden cells) ?

Comment: Don't think about iterating cells. Think about iterating the array that populates the cells. That's what you would need to update. Then the cell reads from that array and gets all the data.

Comment: but I need to loop through all cells to (for example) change the background color of the cells, so nothing to do with the array in this case.

Comment: You will have to check for some kind of condition in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, so the cell draws a different background. But as I said, cells are lazy loaded, so there is no way to access them once they are deallocated.

Comment: Take look at UITableView's visibleCells method. It actually gives you the visible cells in an array.

Comment: @sdsborn I need to loop through all cells (hidden + visible) not only the visible ones.

Comment: There are no 'hidden' cells. They just don't exist. They're gone, dead. Deallocated from memory. You can't access them.

Answer (score 0):

The number of cells which would be created will depend on how many cells are being displayed on the view. In your case only 5 cells are created.

cell = (EditableTableDataRow *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];

this line will make the tableview reuse the created cells. So when you scroll down your first cell will disappear so that created cell for first row be used for 6 th row in your case.

hope it helps.